# Can you help me with my SQL Server query?

Tags: sql-server

I have these tables in my SQL Server database:

**Users**:

```
  Nick     CodCountry    BirthDate
 -----------------------------------
  Chekov        1        2001-09-15
  Kirk          1        1982-01-27
  McCoy         3        2002-02-12
  Scott         3        2001-03-31
  Spock         2        2002-02-12
  Sulu          4        1991-05-02
  Uhura         2        1989-12-21
```

**Play**:

```
  Nick    CodTrivia   MoneyEarned
 ----------------------------------
  Chekov      2            5         
  Kirk        1            500       
  Kirk        3            400       
  Kirk        4            200       
  Kirk        7            300       
  McCoy       2            15        
  McCoy       6            10        
  Scott       6            25        
  Spock       2            50        
  Spock       6            50        
  Sulu        1            200       
  Sulu        4            500       
  Sulu        7            500       
  Uhura       3            200       
  Uhura       7            0
```

And I need  the users that wins more trivias. moneyearned>0  is a win

So far I have this:

```
select * 
from Users
where Nick in (select Nick 
               from Play 
               where MoneyEarned > 0 
               group by Nick 
               having count(Nick) = (select top 1 count(Nick)))
```

But my mind goes blank after that...can someone help me?

Pd: it need to show Kirk because he win 4 time.

Comment: What do you mean by _users who reached the end of more trivia without having lost_?

Comment: That is beacuse the User can end the trivia in Guest quality whit no moneyearned but is not nesesari to this problem. the thing is in Play Table each time you wij a trivia the nick the cod trivia and the money earn is added. so by that logic Kirk win 4 times Sulu win 3 and ect ect. i need to select only the one whit more wins.....when the moneyearned is 0 not count thas why the MoneyEarned>0

Comment: The winner per trivia is the one with most money earned, or if money earned > 0 then it's considered a win?

Comment: if the money earned is >0 then is a win

Comment: Which DMBS are you using? Tag accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group the `play` table by `nick` and count the amount of wins. Retrieve the best one with a `TOP 1 ... ORDER BY COUNT(1)`.

```
;WITH BestPlayer AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1
        P.Nick
    FROM
        Play AS P
    WHERE
        P.MoneyEarned > 0
    GROUP BY
        P.Nick
    ORDER BY
         COUNT(1) DESC, -- Amount of wins
         SUM(MoneyEarned) DESC -- Amount of money
)
SELECT
    U.*
FROM
    Users AS U
    INNER JOIN BestPlayer AS B ON U.Nick = B.Nick
```

You can add `WITH TIES` if you want to display players with the same ranking. (`TOP 1 WITH TIES`)

Comment: that only work when there is 1 as max wins. but if for example there where more than one whit max wins,?

Comment: @FacundoFonseca use TOP 1 WITH TIES, it's mentioned at the bottom. Maybe remove the SUM(MoneyEarned) if you just want to rank over the amount of wins and not also by the money won.

Comment: sorry did'nt see, yes yes it works 
thank you very much you :)